# Is it possible to host a PHP Web Application in SharePoint 2013

Tags: rest, web, php

I have a PHP Web Application hosted in a site which consumes REST API. I would like to know whether it is possible to host that application in SharePoint? I know you could use Page Viewer Web Part. But then the application should be still hosted on some other site.
Is it possible? If not, can any other(programming language) custom based web application be hosted in SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already have the answer - that you can use a PageViewerWebPart - and show the PHP content within SharePoint.

And yes - it would still be hosted on the other server.

You can show any HTML content within a PageViewer or ContentEditor WebPart - what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: I am already using the PageViewerWebPart and I am able to access the application hosted on another server. Actually I would like to know whether  it is possible to host the application within SharePoint itself and not using an external server.

Comment: SharePoint is a very large ASP.NET app, using IIS - and often multiple servers within a farm (2-3 at least).   You can certainly set up another website on the same IIS server, but would need PHP capability - or - you'd have to also run Apache, as well as IIS.

If you can separate, and have the PHP site on a separate server, this would be a better option - performance, etc

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft stack serves ASPX pages from the IIS server on a Windows machine

PHP is a different technology

You can configure your IIS server to serve PHP pages but it requires PHP to be installed on that Windows server.

https://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/phponwindows.aspx